# In list, how can I make modifications to a list through a function which takes the list as a parameter?

Tags: list, lisp, common-lisp, pass-by-value

I was writing a program in Lisp to put the common elements from two lists into a new one. Here is my code.

```
(defun test (a b)
  (let ((alist nil) (blist nil))
    (progn
      (join a b alist blist)
      (print blist))))

(defun join (a b alist blist)
  (cond
   ((and (null a) (null b))
    (setf blist (cons alist blist)))
   ((equal (car a) (car b))
    (setf alist (cons (list (car a) (car b)) alist)))
   (t (join (cdr a) (cdr b) alist blist))))
```

But the output of the function is always`nil`. Then I looked up something on Internet and found out that when I try to use `setf`, it no longer points to the original list, instead it points to a new one. So if I cannot use `setf`, what else can I use to implement this?

Comment: I'm not sure what your function really is supposed to do. Do you want your result to hold elements that are at the same position in two input lists, or do you want some kind of intersection? If the latter, what about duplicates?

Comment: I agree with daniel - this is a confusing function. Can you give some examples of function calls and  expected output? Also, if the function joins two lists together, why does it take four arguments?

Comment: you should always use proper indented Lisp code.

Answer (score 1):

```
(defun test (a b)
  (let ((alist nil) (blist nil))   ; two variables initialized to NIL
    (progn                         ; this PROGN is not needed
      (join a b alist blist)       ; you call a function, but ignore the
                                   ; return value? Why?
      (print blist))))             ; since blist was never modified, this
                                   ; can only be the initial value, NIL



(defun join (a b alist blist)      ; four new local variables
  (cond
   ((and (null a) (null b))
    (setf blist (cons alist blist)))    ; why do you set the variable BLIST?
                                        ; you never use it later

   ((equal (car a) (car b))
    (setf alist (cons (list (car a) (car b)) alist)))
                                        ; why do you set the variable ALIST?
                                        ; you never use it later

   (t (join (cdr a) (cdr b) alist blist))))
                                        ; the only recursive call of JOIN
```

You can only change variables, which are lexically reachable.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use "output" arguments in Lisp. Better return the result from the function.
Also, there is a function 'intersection' in CL which does what you want, so please use it unless it is an exercise (then you can look up its implementation).